# Java hasNext() and element() Implementation in While Loop

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm having problems with my Iterator and Deque method and Here's my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Iterator;





class Customer {
       public String lastName;
       public String firstName;
       public Customer() {
       }
       public Customer(String last, String first) {
          this.lastName = last;
          this.firstName = first;
       }
       public String toString() {
          return firstName + " " + lastName;
       }
    }
    class HourlyCustomer extends Customer {
       public double hourlyRate;
       public HourlyCustomer(String last, String first) {
          super(last, first);
       }
    }

class GenQueue<E> {
   private LinkedList<E> list = new LinkedList<E>();
   public ListIterator<E> iterator = list.listIterator();
   public void enqueue(E item) {
      list.addLast(item);
   }
   public E dequeue() {
      return list.poll();
   }
   public E show(){
       return list.peek();
   }
   public void printQueueElements(){

   }
   public E isNotEnd(){
       return list.getLast();
   }
   public boolean hasItems() {
      return !list.isEmpty();
   }
   public boolean isEmpty()
   {
       return list.isEmpty();
   }
   public Iterator<E>   iterator()
   {
    return iterator;       
   }


   public E removeFirst(){
       return list.removeFirst();
   }
   public E getFirst(){
       return list.getFirst();
   }
   public int size() {
      return list.size();
   }
   public boolean hasNext()
   {
    return false;

   }



   public void addItems(GenQueue<? extends E> q) {

      while (q.hasNext()) list.addLast(q.dequeue());
   }


}





public class Jerald {

    public static void main(String[] args){



        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input1;
        String input2;
        int choice = 1000;




        GenQueue<Customer> empList;
        empList = new GenQueue<Customer>();
        GenQueue<HourlyCustomer> hList;
        hList = new GenQueue<HourlyCustomer>(); 


        while(true){

        do{

            System.out.println("================");
            System.out.println("Queue Operations Menu");
            System.out.println("================");
            System.out.println("1,Enquene");
            System.out.println("2,Dequeue");
            System.out.println("0, Quit\n");
            System.out.println("Enter Choice:");
            try{

                choice = sc.nextInt();



                switch(choice){
                case 1:

                    do{


                    System.out.println("\nPlease enter last name:  ");
                    input1 = sc.next();
                    System.out.println("\nPlease enter first name:  ");
                    input2 = sc.next();
                    hList.enqueue(new HourlyCustomer(input1, input2));
                    empList.addItems(hList);

                    System.out.println("\n"+(input2 + " " +  input1) + " is successful queued");

                    System.out.println("\nDo you still want to enqueue?<1> or do you want to view all in queue?<0> or \nBack to main menu for dequeueing?<menu>: ");
                    choice = sc.nextInt();

                    }while (choice != 0);



                     System.out.println("\nThe customers' names are: \n");

                     int numberOfElements = empList.size();
                     for (int i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++) {
                       Customer emp = empList.dequeue();
                       System.out.println(emp.firstName + " " + emp.lastName + "\n");
                       empList.enqueue(emp);
                     }

                     break;






                case 2:


                    if (empList.isEmpty()) {
                        System.out.println("The queue is empty!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    System.out.println("\nDequeued customer: "  +empList.getFirst());
                    empList.removeFirst();
                    }

                    if (empList.isEmpty()) {
                        System.out.println("The queue is empty!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    System.out.println("\nNext customer in queue: "  +empList.getFirst()+"\n");
                }

                    break;

                case 0:

                    System.exit(0);



                default:
                        System.out.println("Invalid choice");
                }

            }

            catch(InputMismatchException e){
                System.out.println("Please enter 1-5, 0 to quit");
                sc.nextLine();
            }

        }while(choice != 0);
        }
    }
}
```

in case 1, I'm trying to make it retrieve all elements that are in my queue and print it out. Without removing them from there. So basically, instead of using `while(hasItems)` and `poll()` which I accomplished and it showed the output that i want, but it deletes everything in the list, so I came up with another approach and used the hasNext method so I used `while(empLst.hasNext())` with `element()` method which only retrieves but does not delete.  Unfortunately I have failed on this and have been getting either an empty result after many inputs, or an infinite loop after giving even a single input. How do I fix this? Need help. I think its on my implementation, but I think I have checked already. Anyway I need your opinion on this.

by the way in case 2, im removing the first elementof the linkedlist and showing the first element of the removed linkedlist.

Answer (score 0):

In case 1, after the do-while loop you want to print all the elements in the Queue and keep all the elements.

I see 2 possibilities:

1) Implement in GenQueue a method that iterates the inner list and prints each element without changing anything: public void printQueueElements(). 
This is the recommended solution.

2) Instead of:

```
while (empList.hasNext()) {
  Customer emp = empList.dequeue();
  System.out.println(emp.firstName + " " + emp.lastName + "\n" );
}
```

Use:

```
int numberOfElements = empList.size();
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++) {
  Customer emp = empList.dequeue();
  System.out.println(emp.firstName + " " + emp.lastName + "\n");
  empList.enqueue(emp);
}
```

This way the queue regains its elements.

The code for case 3 should be:

```
case 3:
  System.out.println("\nThe customers' names are: \n");
  Iterator<Customer> it = empList.iterator();
```

Note the type of the variable "it". Also, the convention is to call an iterator variable "itr" or "iterator".

Comment: thanks, i implemented step 2, but on step 1 how do I implement it as a method? what do i return?

`public void printQueueElements(){

return ???

}`

Comment: Don't return anything. A method with "void" before its name does not return any value. Also, it appears that you don't really need any value in return, just to print to the screen. Call "list.listIterator(0);" to get an iterator for the elements.

Comment: Hello @Java Guy next door have you tested the code on your side? I already implemented it but still when I'm done adding names, it still shows empty.

Comment: I have edited my code can you please check what I lacked? it runs yes but it never showed the output that i want. It didnt print the queue

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of your infinite loop problem, remove that outer while(true) loop. Cause infinite loops is exactly what those kinds of loops do, and you don't need it to get the kind of flow you want.

I also introduced a third choice to your menu which clears things up a bit, but I guess that's up to you.

As far as your list problems, fix that "dequeue" method in GenQueue so that it actually does a dequeue (removes the first element in the list), then your case 2 becomes easy.

For printing a list without removing its elements, make use of iterators. I got rid of that ListIterator field in your queue class because you don't need it. In fact, most of the methods you have in that class have already been implemented for you anyways. Take a look at the
[List API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

```
class GenQueue<E> {

    private LinkedList<E> list = new LinkedList<E>();

    public void enqueue(E item) {
        list.addLast(item);
    }

    public E dequeue() {

        // return a customer with null values if empty? (up to you)
        if (list.isEmpty())
            return new Customer("","");
        else
            return list.remove(0);
    }

    public E isNotEnd(){

        return list.getLast();
    }

    public boolean hasItems() {

        return !list.isEmpty();
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {

        return list.isEmpty();
    }

    public Iterator<E> iterator() {

        return list.iterator();
    }

    public E removeFirst() {

        return list.removeFirst();
    }

    public E getFirst() {

        return list.getFirst();
    }

    public int size() {

        return list.size();
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {

        return false;
    }

    public void addItems(GenQueue<? extends E> q) {

        while (q.hasNext()) list.addLast(q.dequeue());
    }
}


public class something {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input1;
        String input2;
        int choice = 1000;

        GenQueue<Customer> empList;
        empList = new GenQueue<Customer>();
        GenQueue<HourlyCustomer> hList;
        hList = new GenQueue<HourlyCustomer>();

        do {

            System.out.println("================");
            System.out.println("Queue Operations Menu");
            System.out.println("================");
            System.out.println("1,Enquene");
            System.out.println("2,Dequeue");
            System.out.println("3,View queue");
            System.out.println("0, Quit\n");
            System.out.println("Enter Choice:");

            try {

                choice = sc.nextInt();

                switch(choice) {

                    case 1:

                        System.out.println("\nPlease enter last name:  ");
                        input1 = sc.next();
                        System.out.println("\nPlease enter first name:  ");
                        input2 = sc.next();
                        hList.enqueue(new HourlyCustomer(input1, input2));
                        empList.addItems(hList);

                        System.out.println("\n"+(input2 + " " +  input1) + " is successful queued");

                        break;

                    case 2:

                        System.out.println("Dequeued customer: " + empList.dequeue().toString());

                        break;

                    case 3:

                        System.out.println("\nThe customers' names are: \n");

                        Iterator<Genqueue<Customer>> it = empList.iterator();

                        while (it.hasNext()) {

                            Customer emp = it.next();
                            System.out.println(emp.firstName + " " + emp.lastName + "\n" );
                        }

                        break;

                    case 0:

                        System.exit(0);

                    default:

                        System.out.println("Invalid choice");
                }
            }
            catch(InputMismatchException e) {

                System.out.println("Please enter 1-5, 0 to quit");
                sc.nextLine();
            }

        } while(choice != 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: I got this error on case 3:

lines 154 and 158


154:
`Type mismatch: cannot convert from Iterator<Customer> to Iterator<GenQueue<Customer>>`

158:
`Type mismatch: cannot convert from GenQueue<Customer> to Customer`

Comment: in the public E dequeue 
`Type mismatch: cannot convert from Customer to E` @ClumsySyrup

Comment: did you detect the problem? Because of the errors I cant run it, even though I tried changing the code on my own via the suggestions, but still it returns no list element after adding to the queue.